# Renaming rqt package [Kinetic]

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, rqt, package, gui

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm attempting to renamed my package from rqt_truckee_gui to rqt_truckee but it causes the following error:

```
admin@pc1:~/git/x-ros/catkin_ws$ rqt -s rqt_truckee
[ERROR] [1522742453.102027186]: Skipped loading plugin with error: XML Document '/home/hpcadmin/git/x-ros/catkin_ws/src/truckee/rqt_truckee_gui/plugin.xml' has no Root Element. This likely means the XML is malformed or missing..
RosPluginProvider._parse_plugin_xml() plugin file "/home/hpcadmin/git/x-ros/catkin_ws/src/truckee/rqt_truckee_gui/plugin.xml" in package "rqt_truckee_gui" not found
RosPluginProvider._parse_plugin_xml() plugin file "/home/hpcadmin/git/x-ros/catkin_ws/src/truckee/rqt_truckee_gui/plugin.xml" in package "rqt_truckee_gui" not found
qt_gui_main() found no plugin matching "rqt_truckee"
```

I have removed all build folders and files, run rosclean purge, run catkin_make clean, run rospack profile (after catkin_make) and tried a full power cycle between all these things just for good measure.  It seems like rqt is holding on to the memory of the last package name somewhere outside the catkin workspace.

When I change the package name back everything launches normally:

```
admin@pc1:~/git/x-ros/catkin_ws$ rqt -s rqt_truckee_gui
arguments:  Namespace(quiet=False)
unknowns:  []
appmenu-qt: handleReparent 143 The given QMenuBar is already registered by appmenu-qt5, skipping
appmenu-qt: handleReparent 143 The given QMenuBar is already registered by appmenu-qt5, skipping
```

For now, I can live with the original package name but I was surprised by this functionality.

**Edit:**  @gvdhoom's second answer was correct.  If you are having this problem delete ~/.config/ros.org/rqt_gui.ini and you should be able to rename your package.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/287341/renaming-rqt-package-%5Bkinetic%5D/) by [Taylor Cooper](https://answers.ros.org/users/34456/taylor-cooper/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-04-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-03**:\

> I have removed all build folders and files

unless rebuilding your workspace is really costly, I would just `rm -rf $CATKIN_WS/devel $CATKIN_WS/build`. Renaming build artefacts is rather error prone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There could be an entry in `~/.config/ros.org/rqt_gui.ini`, but from the error messages I doubt that is the issue here.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-04-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Taylor Cooper](https://answers.ros.org/users/34456/taylor-cooper/) on 2018-04-05**:
@gvdhoom's second answer was correct. If you are having this problem delete ~/.config/ros.org/rqt_gui.ini and you should be able to rename your package.